# i have error with multer and nodejs 'EINVAL: invalid argument'

Tags: node.js, api, rest, ubuntu, multer

i tried many solutions but i got the same error,i think it's not from the code because it run's successfully on heroku, i tried another old project that's in production right now and did not run too,and i'm using ubuntu and windows as dual boot and i got this error on ubuntu, i faced this error once when i tried to run the ubuntu created project on windows.

**multer code**

```
    //multer
 const fileStorage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination:(req,file,cb)=>{
      cb(null,'images');
  },
  filename:(req,file,cb)=>{
    cb(null,new Date().toISOString()+'-' + file.originalname);
  }
});




const fileFilter = (req,file,cb)=>{
  if(file.mimetype==='image/png'||
  file.mimetype==='image/jpg'   ||
  file.mimetype==='image/jpeg'){
      cb(null,true);
  }else {
    cb(null,false);
  }
}

//meddleWere
app.use(bodyParser.json());

//multer meddlewere
app.use(multer({storage:fileStorage,fileFilter:fileFilter}).array('image'));
app.use('/images',express.static(path.join(__dirname,'images')));
```

**error: -**

```
    { [Error: EINVAL: invalid argument, open 'images/2020-07-27T20:27:54.840Z-Screenshot from 2020-07-27 20-05-10.png']
  errno: -22,
  code: 'EINVAL',
  syscall: 'open',
  path:
   'images/2020-07-27T20:27:54.840Z-Screenshot from 2020-07-27 20-05-10.png',
  storageErrors: [] }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination:function(req,file,cb){
        cb(null,'./uploads/')
    },
    filename:function(req,file,cb){
        const name =  Date.now()
        cb(null, name + file.originalname)
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to the code that can help understand it.